# \b after \. not catching period

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that matches both `'1'` and `'1.'` but not `'12'`, i.e. the `1` must not be part of a bigger token, and if it's followed by a period, I want to match that too. All quotes here denoting strings.

Why doesn't the pattern `1\.?\b` match the period in the string `'1.'` ?

If I continue the string, it catches the period: `'1.2'`

Since `1\b` matches `'1'`, `\b` must include the end of the string, so I  expected `\.?` to match the period and `\b` to match the end of the string. Why is the period not matched when it is the last character?

Comment: You wanted `1\b\.?`

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no word boundary after the dot. A word boundary is defined as the place where something which isn't a word character is adjacent to something which is.

Maybe you are looking for `\b1\.?`

Comment: That's the key insight I was missing. Neither the period nor the end of string are word characters. `\b1\.?` doesn't work because it allows characters to follow the `1` but `1\b\.?` does. Thank you.